# Could not find RubyGem i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm relatively new to Rails and Ruby, but when I try do rails -s or rails -v I get this error

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem i18n (>= 0.6.4, ~> 0.6) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rails:22
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
```

Not sure what's causing it, or how I can fix it.

**EDIT**

After trying bundle install I get this error:

```
Gemfile syntax error compile error
on line 73: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'thin', group: [:production]
              ^
```

*Line 73 in my Gemfile*

```
gem 'thin', group: [:production]
```

**EDIT 2**

[Gemfile Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0e8118093a64a6287a02)

Comment: Try `bundle install`.

Comment: you have a syntax error in your `Gemfile`. post it

Comment: Try this `gem 'thin', :group => :production`

Comment: `gem 'thin', group: [:production]` worked for me. what is before and after it?

Comment: Added the gem file above

Comment: Do you have rvm installed properly? The stack trace is referencing ruby 1.8 which seems wrong

Comment: Your rvm setup looks broken. It looks like you are (somehow) calling the rvm 2.1.1 executables but with the system Ruby. Make sure you have called `rvm use 2.1.1` (and that it has worked).

Comment: This is what `rvm use 2.1.1` returns `Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is off. Just use this

```
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end
```

Comment: That still throws syntax errors. I added the gem file above

Comment: Can I see the whole gemfile?